# Any easy way to get the last number from "Totals: 955198 147.9M 6 16477 162 962959 1.0 3.4"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to analyze a text file here.

```
$a = (Get-Content c:\tabanalys.txt | Select-String "Total"  -casesensitive).line
```

This returns a string:

```
Totals:               955198  147.9M     6 16477   162     962959    1.0     3.4
```

Now I need to get the last number "3.4" there, this number is variable. I'm thinking of getting it using:

```
$a[-5..-1]
```

This can work for me but obviously is not a absolutely correct answer. So, can anyone suggest any correct answers? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option that doesn't involve regex-fu. Split the string (ignore empty elements) and get the last element:

```
$a.Split(' ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[-1]

3.4
```

or using the match operator (regex pattern):

```
if($a -match '\d+\.\d+$') {$matches[0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$a -split ' ' | select -Last 1
```

or just

```
 ($a -split ' ')[-1]
```